# Tkinter, cuando se programa para la interfaz grafica, queda algo del programa original?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Tengo las siguientes líneas de un programa sencillo.

```
a = input('Introduce el primer numero   :')
b = input('Introduce el segundo numero  :')

suma =  a + b
print ('La suma es :  ',suma)
```

Al programar con Tkinter, queda algo de estas líneas, o se empieza todo de nuevo. Lo único que he logrado es crear una ventana, asi que no se nada de Tkinter. ¿Como sería en Tkinter este programa de suma?

Desde ya gracias por sus respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Como norma general , no puedes usar `input` en una GUI, ni ninguna otra función bloqueante como `time.sleep` en el mismo hilo que tu aplicación. Con bloqueante me refiero a una función, método, expresión, ciclo, etc que tarde en ser evaluada y retornar.

Tkinter como otros frameworks gráficos tienen un ciclo infinito (mainloop) que se encarga de responder a eventos, redibujar la interfaz, etc que no puede bloquearse nunca. Si algún código ejecutado en el mismo hilo lo bloquea la interfaz dejará de responder a eventos y se congelará.

Por tanto, debes usar las alternativas que el framework ofrece o correr el código bloqueante de forma asíncrona, por ejemplo en otro hilo, si no es posible.

Para substituir a `input` simplemente usa el widget `tkinter.Entry`. Un ejemplo muy simplificado:

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
entry1 = tk.Entry(root)
entry1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
entry2 = tk.Entry(root)
entry2.grid(row=0, column=4, columnspan=2)
tk.Label(root, text="+").grid(row=0, column=3)
resultado = tk.Label(root, text="")
resultado.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=6)


def sumar():
    try:
        suma = str(float(entry1.get()) + float(entry2.get()))
    except ValueError:
        suma = "Error"
    resultado.configure(text=suma)


tk.Button(root, text="Sumar", command=sumar).grid(row=2, column=3)
root.mainloop()
```

---

Comment: Pero si quiero que estos dos valores (a y b) queden almacenadas como variables, para ser usadas mas adelante, que tendria que variar?

Comment: Simplemente almacenalas en una variable global desde tu función suma.  Si vas a almcenar varias usa un contenedor como una lista, diccionario, etc.